# Installing Google Assistant on Raspberry pi Zero W

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I am just trying the installation of google assistant on raspberry pi w on current date, just followed Google's Assistant SDK procedure from start till testing, but on final command i.e. `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model`

I am getting output :

```
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Could not create the device instance. Project_id from side channel and project_id from url do not match.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What's that issue? please help!

[Error Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPHDT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, it appears that the `--project-id` you're providing in the command line is not the same id as the project that you logged in with.

When you [setup the project](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device), you need to create a device model and then download a client_secrets file. You will then use the `google-oauthlib-tool` to exchange the client secret for user credentials.

The project ID that you used to create the device model needs to be the same as the project ID that you're providing in the argument.